# Find the expected value of an Y function

Tags: probability

$EX = \int xf(x)dx$, where $f(x)$ is the density function of some X variable. This is pretty understandable, but what if I had, for example an $Y = -X + 1$ function and I had to calculate $EY$? How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the linearity of expectation, we have:
$$
E(Y) = E(-X + 1) = -E(X) + 1
$$

Alternatively, you could use the definition directly. Let $Y=g(X)=-X+1$. Then:
$$ \begin{align*}
E(Y)&=E(g(X))\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x)dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty(-x+1)f(x)dx\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)dx + \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx\\
&=-E(X) + 1
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the expected value of some function $g$ of $X$ using the following formula:

$$E[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f(x)\:dx$$

An explanation for this can be found on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_definition).